# How to allow users to add pictures in my forum?

Tags: php, forum, imgur

I am currently working on a small forum that allows users to make posts as well as comment replies to them. I want users to also be able to post pictures along with their posts directly onto the website. I see that Stack Overflow uses imgur when you want to add pictures to your question. Are there any plug-ins or something that could do this? I've tried searching google, but haven't had much luck.

Comment: See their docs: https://apidocs.imgur.com/#c85c9dfc-7487-4de2-9ecd-66f727cf3139

Comment: @mario This would allow the photos to be visible on my website right? Imgur would just be where the photos are stored?

Comment: If they are going to post on your site you are going to need a lot of room.  Stackoverflow forces people to upload URLs of images, not the image itself.

Comment: @Forbs I'm looking into the URL thing. I upload images (Url's) onto Stack Overflow straight from file explorer, so imgur might be just what I need

Comment: I don't understand all of the downvotes. I would appreciate it if the downvoters could leave reasons in the comments. It would help actually make questions better instead of discouraging posting.

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16 the downvotes are because this is a site where you have a specific problem (not a general) and ask and we answer.  This question is way too general and to answer would take a lot more than a small one line answer.

Comment: @Forbs Ok, thank you for the explanation. I'll be sure to keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score -1):

use this editor in your forum and it saves the images directly to your mysql database.

https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/

let me know if it help you, and don not get discourage of posting.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll be sure to check this out today :)

Comment: This turned out to be very helpful. Thanks for suggesting it.